# How should we punish trolls (if we should at all)?

Tags: support

I want to ask what is the site policy on trolling issues. 
[Here is](https://russian.stackexchange.com/posts/1662/revisions) what I'm talking about.
It is the second time when this very user tries to insult me after 
downvoting his question.

The thing is not about a personal offence. For me, this is only a place where we ask interesting questions and expect to get interesting answers. As for me, I don't care who will answer the question and, if the answer if fine, I'm up voting it without keeping in mind any kind of rancor issues. For example, I've already upvoted an answer provided by this user.

But I am a strong believer that such behaviour should be suppressed as soon as possible.

So, what should I do when I see such behaviour - should I just silently edit it, removing curses each time? Should I flag such answer? If I should, why there was no any kind of actions taken in this very case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens, flag the answer. If it's one issue, we can close an eye because anyone can have a bad day. Nonetheless, such things are not tolerated and we'll edit them out whenever possible.

If the issue is reiterated then by all means, flag the answer and choose custom, and link other issues by the same user. Or ask a moderator to setup a private chat room if the thing needs further discussion but flag anyway first.

If a user keeps abusing their privileges and keep insulting other users, we'll take measures but we're not mindreaders. We don't know if something is going on unless you flag it (or we run into it).

Comment: I'm going to leave a comment saying that it's against our [FAQ](http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette) and edit the answer. If the user ignores it, I'm going to suspend him.

Comment: I don't suppose anybody is a mindreader, I'm also interested in any new member of community. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @shabunc Yes I know you didn't suppose it. Just adding it myself. :P